# How to access my old files(ftp - media files) in windows azure deployment?

Tags: azure

I have migrated and deployed my asp.net (2010) application to windows azure cloud service.

I have small doubts here.

In my previous hosting my application files(media, documents) are located in the local folder of ftp site. And storage (db ) was in server. But according to windows azure i just deployed my application to cloud with db created in windows azure portal.

i). How can i use my previous files here?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you store the files that used to be in FTP in Azure Blob storage https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/. If you put them to blob storage you can use something like Cloudxplorer http://clumsyleaf.com/products/cloudxplorer to browse them and upload them. If you really want to use FTP (which I'd not recommend as it an insecure protocol) there is also a blob storage to FTP bridge http://ftp2azure.codeplex.com/